# Setting a DocumentReference in Document on Firestore (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a doc with a reference on Firestore with NodeJS v8.6.0. Like this

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp({ credential: MY_CREDENTIAL, databaseURL: MY_DB_URL })
const db = admin.firestore()

const ref = db.doc('foo/someDoc')
db.doc('bar/targetDoc').set({ link: ref })
```

Although `ref` is a `DocumentReference`, it results

> Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input object is deeper
>   than 20 levels or contains a cycle.

Is there anyway to do it on NodeJS (Admin)SDK?

---

In addition, the package used in the code is

```
"firebase-admin": "^5.4.1"
```

and

```
console.log(ref)
```

outputs

```
DocumentReference {
  _firestore: 
   Firestore {
     makeAuthenticatedRequest: 
      { [Function: makeAuthenticatedRequest]
        getCredentials: [Function: bound getCredentials],
        authClient: [Object] },
     authClient: 
      Auth {
        authClientPromise: null,
        authClient: null,
        config: [Object],
        environment: {} },
     baseUrl: undefined,
     getCredentials: [Function: bound getCredentials],
     globalInterceptors: [],
     interceptors: [],
     packageJson: 
      { name: '@google-cloud/firestore',
        version: '0.8.1',
        author: 'Google Inc.',
        description: 'Firestore Client Library for Node.js',
        contributors: [Array],
        main: './src/index.js',
        files: [Array],
        repository: 'googleapis/nodejs-firestore',
        keywords: [Array],
        dependencies: [Object],
        devDependencies: [Object],
        scripts: [Object],
        license: 'Apache-2.0',
        engines: [Object],
        types: './types/firestore.d.ts' },
     projectId: 'MY_PROJECT',
     projectIdRequired: true,
     Promise: [Function: Promise],
     grpcMetadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: [Object] },
     maxRetries: undefined,
     userAgent: 'gcloud-node-firestore/0.8.1',
     activeServiceMap_: Map {},
     protos: {},
     _preferTransactions: false,
     _lastSuccessfulRequest: null,
     api: { Firestore: [Object] },
     _referencePath: 
      ResourcePath {
        segments: [],
        _formattedName: undefined,
        _projectId: 'dewpod-dev',
        _databaseId: '(default)' },
     app: 
      FirebaseApp {
        firebaseInternals_: [Object],
        services_: [Object],
        isDeleted_: false,
        name_: '[DEFAULT]',
        options_: [Object],
        database: [Function: bound ],
        auth: [Function: bound ],
        messaging: [Function: bound ],
        storage: [Function: bound ],
        firestore: [Function: bound ],
        INTERNAL: [Object] },
     INTERNAL: FirestoreInternals {} },
  _referencePath: 
   ResourcePath {
     segments: [ 'orgs', 'fooOrg' ],
     _formattedName: undefined,
     _projectId: 'dewpod-dev',
     _databaseId: '(default)' } }
```

and the full error message is

```
/SOME_PATH/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/validate.js:86
        throw new Error(message);
        ^

Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input object is deeper than 20 levels or contains a cycle.
    at Object.exports.(anonymous function) [as isDocument] (/SOME_PATH/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/validate.js:86:15)
    at WriteBatch.set (/SOME_PATH/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/write-batch.js:251:14)
    at DocumentReference.set (/SOME_PATH/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/reference.js:416:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/SOME_PATH/fstest.js:17:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
```

Comment: @NovoLucas Seems that the sample doesn't save any reference. Can you indicate where it is?

Comment: This should work so this could be a dependency issue such that `DocumentReference` fails the instanceof check in `set`.

How are you importing firestore? Are you sure you're only importing it once?

Could you `console.log(ref);`

Also, which version of node are you using?

Comment: @GilGilbert edited the post. Please check. And, yes, I can reproduce it with minimum code with NodeJS v8.6.0. "require('firebase-admin')" once, "admin.initializeApp" once.

Comment: Thanks. We've been able to reproduce this. It's a bug in an interaction between the admin SDK and the regular node SDK. This works via the regular node.js SDK that you can get as described here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/

Comment: Thanks Gil. Looking forward to the patch : )

Comment: @GilGilbert is this issue being tracked anywhere? I'm not seeing any open issues in firebase-admin-node

Comment: We ave an internal bug tracking ti

Comment: Anyway to work around this like a way to manually set it as a reference type ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a bug in an interaction between the admin SDK and the regular node SDK for Firestore.

An update to @google-cloud/firestore 0.8.2 should fix this issue.

You can update your project with `npm update` to get this change.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error when implementing background functions to handle document update events. As the [docs suggest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#writing_data), it is important to avoid infinite loops by checking that you do not inadvertently end up re-triggering the same function:

> Any time you write to the same document that triggered a function, you are at risk of creating an infinite loop. Use caution and ensure that you safely exit the function when no change is needed

And also from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#add-the-makeuppercase-function):

> Caution: Be careful to avoid any situation in which the function's result actually retriggers the function, creating an infinite loop — for example, a function triggered by writes to a specific Cloud Firestore document that terminates by writing to that same path. Also make sure to write functions in an idempotent way, so that they produce the same result if they run multiple times for a single event.